# Symfony keep displaying sensitive development errors in production environnent

Tags: symfony, deployment, production-environment, symfony-2.7

In web/app.php

I have this

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', 'false');
```

I also executed those commands :

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

but I still get sensitive development errors in production environment

Comment: based on which information would you expect to not get errors? which errors are you seeing were?

Comment: all kind of errors are displayed to me, just like i'm working on dev environment. and those are displayed to me the same way are displayed in dev env

Comment: for any reason might you have a system environment variable SYMFONY_DEBUG set to something else but 0?

Comment: yes i have it ... what to do with it, would you clarify more

Comment: SYMFONY_DEBUG
    If 0, debug mode is disabled. Otherwise, debug mode is enabled.

These environment variables are very useful for production servers because they allow you to ensure that commands always run in the prod environment without having to add any command option - taken from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#selecting-the-environment-for-console-commands - so it could overwrite your debug configuration.